# How to tell if flutter app is active in android

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to send push notifications only when the app is not open (after pressing the home screen on an android phone). The issue is, that using 'this.mounted' doesn't work because the page stays mounted when I hit the home screen. I did a bit of research on the lifecycle of flutter pages, and found that the page is neither disposed nor deactivated when pressing the home button.
In short, I need a way to determine whether my flutter app is in the background on an android phone. (When using iOS, the dispose method is called on pressing the home button).
Even if there's something in flutter for detecting when the android home button is pressed, I could manually fix my problem.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [`WidgetsBindingObserver`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) and [`didChangeAppLifecycleState`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver/didChangeAppLifecycleState.html).

You should be able to use this to tell when your application is in the foreground vs in the background. I don't know if this will solve your problem though; assuming you're using firebase, according to the [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver/didChangeAppLifecycleState.html) it should already be doing the behaviour you want.